# Switch web site to mobile css client side with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile-website

I am trying to change the display of my web pages depending on the version of the browser and space on screen. I need to completely change the look of the pages as follow:

- If the site is displayed on a mobile phone I want the mini version.
- If the site is displayed on a desktop browser but the size of the window is too small I want the mini version.
- If the site is displayed on a desktop browser and the window can accommodate the full version I want the full version displayed.
- If no javascript is available the full version should display.

I just started with some pretty basic code which relies on userAgent:

```js
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )
```

Is there a clean way to achieve what I'm trying to do with JQuery for example?

Comment: Related: [best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery). By the way, do you really want the full site to be shown, if the client doesn't support Javascript?

Comment: @asgs This is where I found my current method for querying the mobile browser. But I am not comfortable with the hardcoded version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). Sniffing the user agent is not reliable, and will lead to maintenance headaches in the future. Also, using media queries means no javascript is required which is good from a separation of concerns point of view.